# Expected function or variable error using the "Find" function

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Sub CheckAvailability()

Dim ALU As String
Dim Availability As Integer
Dim Rnge As Range
ALU = InputBox("Input in the ALU to search", "Search ALU")
If Trim(ALU) <> "" Then
   With Sheets("Sheets2").Range("A:A")
   Set Rnge = .Find(what:=ALU, After:=Cells(.Cells.Count), Lookin:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, 
                    Searchorder:=x1byRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rnge Is Nothing Then
                Availability = Application.Goto(Rnge).EntireRow.Cells(5)
                If Availability > 0 Then
                    MsgBox ("The Availability is" + Availability)
                Else
                   MsgBox (" There is none Available")
            Else 
                MSGbox("This ALU does not exist in this report")
            End If
        End With
     End If
End Sub
```

The objective of the code is to allow the user to input a special item code (ALU), then search for the ALU, check whether the ALU actually exists, and give the corresponding availability of the item from another column. When I try to run the code it highlights the "Goto" and gives me that error message. Any ideas?

Comment: What value does `rnge` hold when you get to the `application.goto` line?

Comment: What do you mean by `.EntireRow.Cells(5)`?

Comment: If Availability does not have a closing end if.

Comment: @SamuelEverson That rnge holds no value. It can't be computed.

Comment: @Harun24HR I wanted it to adopted to value of the 5th cell in the row, that is where the availability column is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the value from 5 column from find cell then use `Offset()` of `Rnge` like `Rnge.Offset(, 5)`. Try below codes.

```
Public Sub CheckAvailability()
Dim ALU As String
Dim Availability As Integer
Dim Rnge As Range

ALU = InputBox("Input in the ALU to search", "Search ALU")
If Trim(ALU) <> "" Then
   With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
   Set Rnge = .Find(What:=ALU, _
                After:=.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rnge Is Nothing Then
                Availability = Rnge.Offset(, 5)
                If Availability > 0 Then
                    MsgBox ("The Availability is: " & Availability)
                Else
                   MsgBox (" There is none Available")
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox ("This ALU does not exist in this report")
            End If
        End With
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! You resolved the problem, but I noticed that my code keeps giving me "This ALU does not exist..." even though I am testing it with ALUs that do exist. I took of the "If trim..." and it is saying that value of the ALU Input expression is "Out of context" in the watch window. Any Ideas with that?